# Setting SSH trust between 2 service accounts

Tags: ssh-keygen

I am trying to setup SSH trust (for passwordless authentication) between 
`user1@host1` TO `user2@host2` so that `user1@host1` can execute remote scripts as `user2@host2`.

Both accounts, `user1` and `user2` are accounts without passwords. I have access to root account on both hosts (which means I can become `user1@host1` and `user2@host2`).

Here is what I have done so far:

```
On host1 as user1:
ssh-keygen -t rsa

Copied the contents of .pub file generated from above 
command to host2:~user2/.ssh/authorized_keys

Changed the permissions on host2:~user2/.ssh to 644 and host2:~user2/.ssh/*.pub to 600
```

Now, when I try to login from `user1@host1` to `user2@host2`, I get prompted for `user2@host2` password, but since this account was created without a password, I can't input that there. I believe `~user2/.ssh/ (on host2)` will need a known_hosts file which will only be created if I am able to successfully login at least once from `user1@host1`. Is there an alternative way to generate contents that I may add to file `~user2/.ssh/known_hosts`?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create a `known_hosts` file, you need to create an `authorized_keys` file. It will contain the public key of `user1@host1`. Given what you've done so far, simply rename the `.pub` file you created in `~user2/.ssh/` to `authorized_keys` and you should be okay.

Comment: Sorry, I failed to mention that I did copy .pub file contents to `authorized_keys` file. I am still getting password prompt as indicated in my question.

Comment: I found the problem with my setup. I didn't use the default names `(id_rsa, id_rsa.pub)` for the key files as I had existing files  in my `.ssh` folder already. I ended up adding config file that would direct SSH to read right  private key file for SSH connections depending on the host names.

Answer (score 1):

The only host that needs the `known_hosts` file is the host being connected *from*.  The missing piece is that you say you've copied the public key over to the remote host, but you imply that it's simply e. g. `id_rsa.pub`.  Rename that file to `authorized_keys` and ensure that you have permissions on `host2` set as follows:

- `/home/user2/.ssh/` - 0700
- `/home/user2/.ssh/authorized_keys` - 0644

You should then, on `host1`, be able to `ssh user2@host2`.